# Two branches with shared code - how to do that in git?

Tags: android, git

I've a problem with organising my Android app's repository. My client wants to have two language versions but unfortunately the translations differ so much that I have to adjust the layout files quite heavily for one language. App is still in development so any fixes to the actual code should be present in both language versions.

Right now my repo looks like this:
branch called appENGLISH
branch called appFRENCH (branched from appENGLISH with 2 additional commits fixing the layout issues)

and now I need to make a change to the code shared by both branches how do I do that most effectively in git?

Comment: Try solving your problem using [Build Flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors). Or even better, supply different layout files in the proper resource folders: `layout` and `layout-fr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use three branches. Each branch should be a project.

- core
- english
- french

The *core*  project (store in the *core* branch) should be a library used by both *english* and *french* projects. It stores all the common code.

Every other way can be easiest but not very "clean". So maybe it will works for this time, but it will bring you a lot of difficulties in the future.

(PS : I answer the question about Git and do not discuss about "why you make two Android app" which is another question IMHO. If you want some point of view about that, leave a comment and I will update my answer)

Comment: I get it (even considered it myself), but it's the <<android way>> of fixing the problem. How could it be solved purely in git?

Comment: It's not a "git" way but a way to manage your project or your code. It's not "normal" to have duplication of code in two branches ;) You *should not* create any duplication to keep your project clean. So I really think this is the best way to solve the problem : make your project clean.